# Как сделать приложение не отключаемым

Tags: java, android

Я знаю, что можно приложение сделать системным, но как мне его сделать не отключаемым? Что мне надо прописать в манифесте приложения?

Comment: Сервис надо сделать, неубиваемый

Comment: Что именно надо добавить в манифест приложения?

Comment: Манифест приложения это мелочи

Comment: Я имею ввиду, чтобы приложение невозможно было отключить. Например системное приложение настройки, как оно сделано так? Даже если приложение сделать системным, его можно будет отключить.

Comment: Google последовательно борется с такой практикой, в целях экономии батареи. Лучше избегать такой архитектуры.